# How can I replace the nth occurence using regex in VBA?

Tags: excel, regex, vba

E.g. I tried to replace the 2nd occurence of a number in "This 9 is 8 a 77 6 test" with "hello".

So I wanted the result to be "This 9 is hello a 77 6 test".

Instead, I'm getting "hellohello test".

I'm using:

```
=RegexReplace("This 9 is 8 a 77 6 test","(?:\D*(\d+)){2}","hello")
```

where RegexReplace is defined below.:

```
Function RegexReplace(text As String, pattern As String, replace As String)

        Static re As Object

        If re Is Nothing Then
            Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
            re.Global = True
            re.MultiLine = True
        End If

        re.IgnoreCase = True
        re.pattern = pattern
        RegexReplace = re.replace(text, replace)
        Set re = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use

```vb
=RegexReplace("This 9 is 8 a 77 6 test","^(\D*\d+\D+)\d+","$1hello")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Gl8Ct/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\D*\d+\D+)` - Group 1: zero or more non-digits + one or more digits + one or more non-digits (this value will be restored in the result using the numbered replacement backreference `$1`)
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

To replace the *third* number, you can refactor the pattern into `^(\D*(?:\d+\D+){2})\d+`. Note the location of the capturing and non-capturing parentheses.

Comment: How could I include negative numbers in this? I tried `^(\D*(?:-?\d+\D+){2})-?\d+` but that didn't work

Comment: @olly `^((?:.*?\b\d+){N-1}.*?)-?\d+` where `N` needs to be adjusted to your requirements. This can be further simplified (`{1}` is redundant, `{0}` makes no sense as you can remove the whole group then).